# Sidebar Issues in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which should work but the

tags are showing up jumbled (2 to a row) instead of one to a row.  I am working in a Laravel project but I don't think that has any impact.  Any idea why the

tags are not showing up correctly?

I have to write more details on here so this submission goes through since there is a lot of code.  You can disregard this section.  Thanks for your help.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500');

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Toggle Styles */

#viewport {
  padding-left: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

#sidebar {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #37474F;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar header {
  background-color: #263238;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar header a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar header a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar .nav{

}

#sidebar .nav a{
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #455A64;
  color: #CFD8DC;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 16px 24px;
}

#sidebar .nav a:hover{
  background: none;
  color: #ECEFF1;
}

#sidebar .nav a i{
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    

</head>

<body>

<div id="viewport">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar">
    <header>
      <a href="#">Plan Builder</a>
    </header>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-view-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-link"></i> Shortcuts
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-widgets"></i> Overview
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></i> Events
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-info-outline"></i> About
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-settings"></i> Services
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-comment-more"></i> Contact
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Content -->
  <div id="content">
        @include('inc\navbar')
      </div>
    </nav>
            <main class="py-4">    
                 @yield('content')
            </main>
                  @include('inc\footer')

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the community. Please make use of  [ Stack Snippets ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)   or https://jsfiddle.net/ to create snippets for easy understanding of the problem

Comment: There is an </nav> tag without an opening tag in the code